# Seaborn Violinplot change order of hue

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to draw split violins to compare them across the hue variable. The plotting itself works fine, but I would like to have the order of the hue variables changed (i.e. 'True' being on the left side of the split instead of on the right). A small working example is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_bool': pd.Series(np.random.choice([True,False],20),dtype='bool'),
                'value': pd.Series(np.random.choice(200,20),dtype='int'),
                'my_group': np.random.choice(['A','B'],20)})
sns.violinplot(x='my_group',data=df,y='value',hue='my_bool',split=True, palette = {True:'blue', False:'red'})
```

This is how the output looks like:
[image]

What I want to achieve is having the False entries on the right of each split, the True entries on the left. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `hue_order`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_bool': pd.Series(np.random.choice([True,False],20),dtype='bool'),
                'value': pd.Series(np.random.choice(200,20),dtype='int'),
                'my_group': np.random.choice(['A','B'],20)})
sns.violinplot(x='my_group',data=df,y='value',hue='my_bool', hue_order= [True, False], split=True, palette = {True:'blue', False:'red'})
```

Comment: I looked at the documentation several times and somehow managed to not see this. Thank you!

Comment: @emilaz `order` or `hue_order` both work and accept lists of any type.